# SQLite on C#. Select query does not work with string of letters

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm learning C# since the past week and databases since a couple of days ago, so if you see something dodgy and you ask yourself "Why did he do that like that?", the answer is probably going to be "Because that's all I know for the moment".

In the title I said "of letters" because if I use a string of numbers, it works.

I have a tiny database with three columns. Id (int), FirstName (text) and LastName (text).
Id is unique, primary key and autoincrements. FirstName is unique. The three are not null.
In that database I have two records:

Id FirstName LastName

3- 6666 2222

4- Test O'Test

This is my method:

```
public static bool isOnDb(string nombre, string apellido)
{
    bool flag = false;
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                string tempName = "Test"; // This is temporarily replacing the argument 'nombre'
                int tempNum= 3; // More testing. See below
                //cnn.Query<Person>($"select * from Person where FirstName = { tempName }", new DynamicParameters());

                // This four lines below are just for testing. They are going to be deleted
                var output = cnn.Query<Person>($"select * from Person where FirstName = { tempName }", new DynamicParameters());
                var person = output.First();
                Console.WriteLine("Funciona");
                Console.WriteLine($"{ person.Id } - { person.FullName }");

                flag = true;
                return flag;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derecho a excepcion");

            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if tempName = "Test", it falls into an exception. But if tempName = "6666" it returns the row.
I also tried selecting by id. That's why tempNum is there.

```
int tempNum= 4;
var output = cnn.Query<Person>($"select * from Person where Id = { tempNum }", new DynamicParameters());
```

Comment: Your error happens because you are not enclosing your value in single quotes as required for strings. But this will be again an error if you try to query on the LastName where the value to search for contains a single quote. Learn how to use parameters. That empty new DynamicParameters is the key

Comment: @Steve You mean changing { tempName } for 'tempName'? I did tried that and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in SQLite the strings are signified by '' so when you pass `FirstName = { tempName }` and its FirstName = Test it looks for the column called Test in Table person rather than equating it to the 'Test' string

So you can do:

```
var output = cnn.Query<Person>($"select * from Person where FirstName = '{ tempName }'");
```

Or better yet:

```
var people = cnn.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE FirstName = @FirstName", new { FirstName = tempName });
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I understand why the strange "no such column: Test" exception. Gotta pay more attention to that next time! And thank you! Now it work wonders!